# Error: Element numerics.length is not supported

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, html, visual-studio

I need your support for solving following error.

https://jsfiddle.net/owbx8fnk/4/

```
// Initialize values
var numerics = document.body.querySelectorAll(".numeric-wrapper input");
for(var i=0; i<numerics.length; ++i){
  toggleNumericDisplay(numerics[i], true);
  numerics[i].addEventListener("focus", focusFunction);
  numerics[i].addEventListener("blur", blurFunction);
}
```

Comment: There is no error here. It is visual studio warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've got javascript directly inside a `<form>` element. It should always be inside a `<script>` element, or in a separate .js file.